# WordPress custom post templates

Tags: wordpress

I am new in WordPress world. I created custom post successfully and I displayed it on page template page. Now I want to use taxonomy-`{category}.php` and `single-{post}.php` for displaying custom post but I am confused in taxonomy page and single page. How can I achieve this?

In `taxonomy-{category}.php` here category means our custom category name or others?

In `single-{post}.php` here post means custom post name or others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [Template_Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) on the [Wordpress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/)

> - taxonomy-{taxonomy}.php - If the taxonomy were sometax, WordPress
>     would look for taxonomy-sometax.php
> - single-{post_type}.php - If the post type were product, WordPress would look for single-product.php.

**Example:**

For *post_type*

When on an online store custom post type in the backend, the URL would be `wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=store`.
So the `post_type` in this case is `store`, which means I will name my file `single-store.php`

For *taxonomy*

When on the Categories page for the online store in the backend, the URL would be `edit-tags.php?taxonomy=store_categories&post_type=store`

So the taxonomy file would be `taxonomy-store_categories.php`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In taxonomy-{category}.php here category means our custom category name or others?

```
taxonomy-{category}.php here category means your custom category(taxonomy)
```

In single-{post}.php here post means custom post name or others?

```
single-{post}.php here post means custom post type name
```

Comment: Thanks for support. If i created taxonomy name "book" so i have to give taxonomy-book.php and this taxonomy page automatically display from my page template page? am i right?